# How to scrape m3u8 from Network-Stream after a js reload (Python)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, m3u8

i run a python program using `beautifulsoup` and `requests` to scrape embedded videos URL , but to download theses videos i need to bypass a  ads popups and `javascript` reload only then the `m3u8` files start to appear in the network traffic;

so i need to simulate the clicks to get to the `javascript` reload (if there's a method better than selenium, trying to reduce script dependencies) and then when the `m3u8`files appear i need to get their url.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule against using selenium side by side with beautifulsoup and requests. You can use the selenium to bypass the clicks, popups and ads and use beautifulsoup and requests to download the videos after the urls have appeared. You can redirect selenium to different urls using the results you get from running a `requests.get()` or similar or you could result to using **[scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)**(a full-blown scraping framework) and with a couple of third party plugins to handle those JavaScript and ads you should be able get those videos in not time.

Answer (score -1):

> Blockquote
>   `i run a python program using beautifulsoup and requests to scrape embedded videos URL , but to download theses videos i need to bypass a ads popups and javascript reload only then the m3u8 files start to appear in the network traffic;

so i need to simulate the clicks to get to the javascript reload (if there's a method better than selenium, trying to reduce script dependencies) and then when the m3u8files appear i need to get their url

`Can I have your code please?